# Two different Pythonpaths and how can I change them?

Tags: python, macos, pythonpath

Since I upgraded my Mac from Mountain Lion to Mavericks my Workflows from Automator and crontab don't work anymore. I found out, that the terminal normally uses a path within the /Library folder, while the Workflows and crontab use a path which begins with /System/Library. How can I change this path to the /Library-path? Because my modules are installed to this /Library path

Comment: And how do you normally do it? Or used to do it but it doesn't work anymore? And what is the problem **exactly**?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your .profile so that your custom built python is found before your system python.

Add this to your ~/.profile:

```
#PYTHON
export PATH=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/VERSION_NUMBER/bin/:$PATH
```

You can test this by typing `which python` before and after to see what is called by default.It may require a system reboot so that the new paths are read in.

Comment: `which python` gives me that: `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python
this path is the one I want and the trick with the ~/.profile file doesn't work for me even after a reboot.